# Bootstrap - How to set middle column element to render full width on mobile and browser collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, I have this code:

```
 <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                    <h2>How to Enjoy Eating Bugs <small>3/6/2015</small></h2>
                    <p> I eat bugs for a living...yum!, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.scing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

The output when the page is displayed on desktop is perfect.

[image]

When I collapse the page the render does not look the way I want and looks like this:

[image]

When the page is collapsed I want the render to look like this:

[image]

I could experiment with media queries to accomplish this but I assume there is probably a simpler "bootstrap" way solve the problem. Please answer with minimal example code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the classes to `col-md-6 col-md-offset-3`

It should go full width when the screen size is under bootstrap's definition of medium (992px)

Comment: @ZimSystem Thanks for fixing my typo!

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-12 col-md-offset-0">
```

You can change md with lg or xl.

For more info about bootstrap grid system I suggest you to look [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/), it's full of useful examples

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 2 modes that you want to support, then Stephen Lander's answer is the elegant solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43876855/257090

However, if you want to be explicit, or if you have more than 2 modes, you can set distinct offset/widths for each screen size so the offset will upshift/downshift with device size.

As the size shrinks, you will want to reduce or eliminate the offset, ie. only use offset on the md or lg styles.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-7 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0">

</div>
```